# Does the fact that Google App Engine supports naked domains with A records mean that GAE IPs are effectively static?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, paas

[Originally](http://web.archive.org/web/20080913190323/http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en-in&answer=61057), Google App Engine only supported subdomains, as it uses a CNAME to resolve your domain to IPs addresses, presumably so that Google can shuffle around IP addresses between customers if needed to better distribute traffic, and they can just update the `A` records their DNS server (the one you CNAME'd to) returns.

Because CNAMEs are not [*technically*](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/#norootforyou) supposed to exist alongside any other DNS records for the same host according to the RFC spec, they are forbidden as `@` (domain root) records, thus GAE only supporting subdomains.

However, in 2014 GAE began supporting naked domains, which it does by [providing you with four `A` records](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) to add to your domain's root DNS records.

**Wouldn't this imply that GAE IP addresses are stable, and effectively static?**

If Google App Engine is telling users to set four `A` records pointing directly to four IP addresses, those IPs *cannot* change without me manually updating my DNS records, outside of Google's control.

This *feels to me* like a major deviation from one of underlying tenets of Google App Engine and other platform-as-a-service providers: namely that you do not get a dedicated server IP address, and cannot assume your IP is stable. In fact, it would appear that every GAE service now gets **four** static IP addresses.

Or is this not as big a deal as I'm inferring?

Comment: Hi @JacobFord as far as the official documentation [indicates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb#private-ip), that no, GAE doesn't gets or uses, four static IP addresses. Actually, GAE doesn't support static IP addresses, but you can use other tools such as Cloud Load Balancing and serverless NEGS, to reserve static IP addresses for you. Could you please provide more details on your worries on it or if this information answers your doubts?

Comment: I'm asking exactly what you point out: GAE says it does not provide static IP addresses. **Yet**, if you host a GAE app on a root domain, GAE Domains provides you four `A` records that point to 4 IP addresses. That means they can't change like they could with a CNAME record. I suppose the key here might be that those IP addresses aren't _private_ (you don't get your site if you type them in directly), but they're definitely _static_, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Sure, I understand @JacobFord however, I think the main point here is that this is only a feature of GAE that works differently from GAE itself and as the documentation informs, it doesn't use static IP addresses. To summarize, I would say that **no**, GAE doesn't use static IP addresses and such type of working it's only used for custom naked domains. Besides that, you can always contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) directly to confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't the same as a static IP address.  For example, suppose the A record for my app is 1.2.3.4.  If I go to http://1.2.3.4 or https://1.2.3.4, then I get an error.

I don't understand the magic that Google goes through with these A records, but it doesn't function the same way that a static IP would.  I suspect that many GAE apps share the same A record since IPv4 addresses are in short supply.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the short answer is they _are_ *static*, but not *private*. I've also been reading up on [anycast IPs](https://www.keycdn.com/support/anycast) and suspect all GAE IPs are anycasted. Still raises the question though of whether it's up to _you_ whether to use a CNAME or A record set for _any_ GAE instance, even though Google tells you specifically which to use, based on whether you're registering a subdomain or naked domain.